# Cannot read property 'value' of null function problem

Tags: javascript, typeerror

So a makind something with js, and the following error is happening:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at addNumber (index.js:27)
at index.js:7

### Things I already tryied to do:
Remove de parentheses from the addNumber on line 7;
Do an onclick function instead of an EventLister
Remove the .value of the var num (it works but returns 0.0 on the input)

Notice: the code isnt ready yet but im pretty sure that I had to be reciving the message errors that I coded.

```
var addBtn = document.querySelector('input#addBtn').style.cursor = "pointer"
var analyzeBtn = document.querySelector('input#analyzeBtn').style.cursor = "pointer"
var list = document.getElementById('list')
var num = document.getElementById('num')
var inp = []

addBtn.addEventListenr('click', addNumber())

function isNumber(n){
  if(Number(n) >=1 && Number(n) <=100){
     return true
 } else {
     return false
 }
}

function inList(n, l) {
  if(l.indexOf(Number(n)) != -1){
    return true
 } else {
    return false
 }
}

function addNumber (){

  if(inList(num.value) && isNumber(num.value, inp)){
    inp.push(Number)
    list.innerHTML += `${inp}`
 } else {
     window.alert('Invalid')
 }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo here `addEventListenr`, also you should remove the parenthesis

Comment: Even if spelled correctly, `addEventListener` expects a function as its second argument `addNumber()` is _not_ a function.

Comment: Try to `console.log(addBtn)` (after fixing typo).

Comment: where you use num.value, can you check if num is not undefined?

Comment: I did a console.log on addBtn after fix and it returned the "pointer", aparently thats one of the issues. Now the error persists on line 27 with Cannot read property 'value' of null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isNumber` function is having two paramters instead of one parameter as defined.

`inList` function is having one parameter instead of two as defined.